# RouteConfig and filename with extension - MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have the following URLs:

```
/Meetings/doc1.pdf
/Meetings/doc2.pdf
```

I tried to set up the following in my RoouteConfig

```
var route = routes.MapRoute(
                name: "RedirectMeetingDocs",
                url: "Meetings/{filename}",               
                defaults: new { action= "GetAttachmentByName", controller = "Generic" },
                constraints: new { filename = @"(.*?)\.(pdf|ppt)" }
            );
```

With the following function:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetAttachmentByName(string fileName)
        {
...
}
```

However, it nevers work and I keep getting a 404 error.

I also tried:

```
var route = routes.MapRoute(
            name: "RedirectMeetingDocs",
            url: "Meetings/{filename}.{extension}",
          
            defaults: new { action= "GetAttachmentByName", controller = "Generic" },
            constraints: new { filename = new AlphaRouteConstraint(), extension = new AlphaRouteConstraint() }
        );
```

with

```
public ActionResult GetAttachmentByName(string fileName, string extension)
        {
```

But nothing works.

Any advices?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solve it by adding the following in my Web.config:

```
<add name="IATTCRedirectOldMeetingFiles" path="meetings/*" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Now, both RouteConfig shown above work.

Comment: I have same problem. Nice solution. You saved my day. First +1 vote !